# Mandar un texto a un label en html apartir de un selec

Tags: javascript, select, condiciones

Estoy tratando de realizar un formulario que dependiendo lo que seleccionen mande un texto a un label

he intentado esto:

[image: crear dos if para cada opción dentro del select y dependiendo de eso mande un texto al label para completar la oración con la opción seleccionada]

Answer (score 0):

Encierra tu código en una funcion y ponla en el evento onchange del select

```
<script>
function cambiarEtiqueta(){
  //El codigo en javascript que ya tienes
}
</script>

<select onchange="cambiarEtiqueta()">
   <!--Las opciones que ya tienes-->
</select>
```